# wxPython, or PyGame canvas within wxPython -> which is faster?

Tags: python, opencv, wxpython, pygame

My goal is to capture frames from a webcam as efficiently as possible using OpenCV. At the moment I'm able to capture 30FPS 6408*480 drawing directly onto a wxPython panel using the standard drawing context (BufferedPaintDC), with about 15% CPU usage (older Core Duo processor). What I'm curious is what sort of performance boost (if any) I'll see if I embed a PyGame canvas within a wxPython frame, and draw directly to the PyGame canvas.

What I'm not sure about is whether the bottleneck is the wxPython frame, and if embedding a PyGame canvas will actually do anything. Or does the wxPython frame act simply like a container and has no influence on the PyGame canvas? I'm hoping I'm making sense here.

The other option would be to use PyGame exclusively, however I really like the functionality of the wxPython widgets, so I'd hate to lose that.

Or is there a faster canvas that I can integrate into wxPython that I'm not aware of?

Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I would imagine that using PyGame by itself would be faster than wxPython, as then the CPU doesn't have to render the wxPython canvas AND the PyGame canvas, but instead just render the PyGame canvas. Also, I presume that 6408*480 as 640*480, right?

Comment: Also I think it might have alot more to do with *how* you are doing the paint routine and whether much of it is being done in an optimzed C call or not

Comment: Yup 640*480, ha. I performed a couple tests and it appears with OpenCV and drawing directly to a PyGame canvas, I can't detect any improvement in efficiency. Maybe sticking with wxPython is the best choice afterall.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd want to embed a gaming library into wxPython in the hopes of gaining a performance boost. Personally, I don't think that will happen. You should take a look at the currently supported drawing canvases that wxPython provides instead or explain what you're trying to do. People have done in games in wxPython...

Anyway, the main drawing interfaces for wx today are wx.GCDC / wx.GraphicsContext, cairo, FloatCanvas, or GLCanvas. Of course, there are also wx.DC, wx.PaintDC and the one you found as well.

Comment: How does PaintDC compare with cairo and glcanvas in terms of performance? My goal is to draw frames from a webcam onto a canvas at at least 30fps with minimal CPU usage. I'm using PyGame to capture gamepad events (in the same app), so I have the library at my disposal, and I've heard it's pretty good with heavy amounts of drawing. Using bufferedpaintdc, drawing 600 lines every 25ms eats up a lots of processor cycles, curious what it would be like with PyGame. I figure if drawing lines is more efficient with PyGame, so should drawing images. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: I'm not really sure as I haven't tested that. You should ask on the wxPython Google group where the devs behind some of those libs live. They can tell you.